# How to add Column header to a ListView in C#

Tags: c#, linq, listview, lambda

i'm having a ListView control with no columns.

an a list

```
List<String> MyList=new List<string>();
```

i need to create columns for each list `MyList` item in the `ListView` along with one another column for Serial Number.

For example if `MyList` contains `"A", "B" ,"C"`

then the list view will be like

[image]

I know that we can do this using `for` or `foreach` loop  like

```
listView1.Columns.Add("S.No")
for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count;i++)
   {
      listView1.Columns.Add(MyList[i])
   }
```

but is there any way to do this using `LINQ` or `LAMBDA Expression`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MyList.ForEach(name => listView1.Columns.Add(name));
```

Comment: i need to add the "S.No" column with this.

Comment: You do not have to add S.No with Linq. Linq is just a shortcut for writing loops that makes code readable, nothing more. If you have to, add S.No as the first item  in the list using InsertAt of the list.

Answer (score 5):

Here are 4 options
there are at least another 10 ways to do this,

```
var myList = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };

// 1: Modify original list and use List<>.ForEach()
myList.Insert(0, "S. No");
myList.ForEach(x => lisView.Columns.Add(x));

// 2: Add first column and use List<>.ForEach()
listView.Columns.Add("S. No");
myList.ForEach(x => listView.Columns.Add(x));

// 3: Don't modify original list
(new[] { "S. No" }).Concat(myList).ToList()
    .ForEach(x => listView.Columns.Add(x));

// 4: Create ColumnHeader[] with Linq and use ListView.Columns.AddRange()
var columns = (new[] { "S. No"}).Concat(myList)
    .Select(x => new ColumnHeader { Text = x }).ToArray();
listView.Columns.AddRange(columns);
```

Have you considered the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) option?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it a little clearer what Aliostad wrote and what the comments below this answer means:

So you currently have this code:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("S.No")
for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count;i++)
{
    listView1.Columns.Add(MyList[i])
}
```

As you already mentioned you can write it also with a `foreach`. This would look like this:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("S.No")
foreach(var item in MyList)
{
    listView1.Columns.Add(item)
}
```

In the second example it also iterates over the list. All it does it hides the local index variable `i`.

With this third example you're no going to hide also this iterating in a function that needs an action what to do with each item in the list:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("S.No")
MyList.ForEach(name => listView1.Columns.Add(name));
```

Under the hood it still iterates over all the elements and performs some functionality on each element. You just don't write the loop by yourself, but that doesn't mean that it is in any way faster or better than your approach. It's just another (shorter) way to tell what you want to achieve.