# Add columns (column headers) to a list view programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I have an array of strings and I want these strings to be the columns(column headers or column names) of the list view. No. of strings is not known until run time and columns are to be added programmatically.
Basically I want to define how many columns will be there in the list view.
Suppose string contains strings = {"str1","str2","str3"}.
I want the list view to contain three columns namely "str1" ,"str2" and "str3".
I want to know the list view property or method that can do add these.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually I am new to asp.net and this not my part to do.My job was to provide the data to bind to the list view and that is not happening due to the mentioned problem.

Comment: Then you've probably come to the wrong place to ask your question. This is not a place to come and ask people to write your code for you free of charge. if you try researching it, try a couple of things and you still can't get it to work then come back with the problems you've encountered.

Comment: can't help you if we don't know what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Column header to a ListView in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077392/how-to-add-column-header-to-a-listview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @sr28 I tried that but it does not show any listview **column** property and since column headers are used, I am guessing it is windows control while the question is around web forms. Thats why I wanted to find out the property I could use to add columns.

Comment: If you've tried something then it's a good idea to add that to the question so people have a better idea of what to suggest.

Comment: Can you display the code you have for the listview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with a list view, but I've done this with a grid view, setting `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
foreach(var col in arrayOfStrings)
    dt.Columns.Add(col);
// add rows to datatable
// of course, set the datasource of the listview/gridview
listview.DataSource = dt;
listview.DataBind();
```